# How do I make a custom markItUp preview page in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, richtextbox, markitup

I have a question about markItUp!'s preview function.

Inside jquery.markitup.js i have these settings:

```
previewTemplatePath:'~/templates/preview.php',
previewParserPath:'~/templates/preview.php',
previewParserVar:'data'
```

I'm not sure what to do with *previewParserPath* and *previewParserVar*. Is it possible to grab the content sent by markItUp in preview.php with PHP?

```
// preview.php
<body>
<!-- content -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 7):

You only need to set the previewParserPath and optionally the previewParserVar.

If you use this:

```
previewParserPath: '~/preview.php'
```

then markitup will look for a preview.php script to run in the same directory as the markitup jquery script--that's what the ~ character means.

If instead you set the preview path to something like this:

```
previewParserPath: '/preview.php'
```

then it will be relative to your web server root directory, as usual.

The implementation of the script it up to you; this is perhaps the most basic example:

```
echo htmlentities($_POST['data']);
```

The "data" there corresponds to the value of the previewParserVar setting; the default is "data".

In your app, you're probably going to want to do something useful with $_POST['data'] before you display it.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work, it complains "data" doesn't exist